# Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS breaking down and sluggish

Tags: 12.04

I am in the process of switching from Windows to a Linux based system and am currently deciding between distributions...I am currently trying Ubuntu as WUBI. I find that my experience is not very smooth and streamlined for example, crash-reports, bugs, applications taking time to run etc etc (this in spite of the fact that I am very patient and am constantly researching solution to different driver and application issues). Was wondering if this is because I am running through NTFS right now or is it just like this? Looking to switch to Linux because of its opensource nature, interest in software development in college as well as maximizing the potential of my machine. I am running an AMD quadcore-x64 2.2GHz, 6GB RAM and 750 GB HDD  on an HP G6 notebook. I would appreciate any honest opinions.

Answer (score 1):

I would just try re-downloading and reinstalling Wubi. If that doesn't work, try upgrading to 12.10.

If neither of the above work, try dual-booting 12.04/12.10 with Windows.

If nothing works, then here is how to safely uninstall:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/

I know that this says to use a Windows CD, but if you don't have one, then just run [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from an Ubuntu live usb/cd (it can repair Windows partitions as well).

If you're really bent on using Linux rather than Windows, you can know for sure that it will work if you buy a machine that has Linux pre-installed. You can buy machines like this from [various places](http://linuxpreloaded.com/), but I highly recommend [Zareason](http://zareason.com/shop/home.php) and [System 76](https://www.system76.com/). You might pay a little more for their machines, but from what the reviews say it's worth it, and what they sell is built to last.